# Ошибка при определении операторов

Tags: c++

Прошу помочь решить ошибку.

> По заданию, нужно определить операторы =,
> +, - , *, +=, -=, *= с целым числом и определить операторы =, +, - , *, +=, -=,
> *= с числом типа longdouble, операторы ++ и --. Но при компиляции выбивает ошибку: существует несколько операторов "+=", соответствующих
> этим
> операндам:    lab18.3 D:\Лабараторки\lab18\lab18.3\lab18.3\Source.cpp 149

```
    using namespace std;
class Mass
{
private:
    long double* p;
    int sizemass;
public:
    Mass() {
        sizemass = 1;
        p = new long double[1];
        p[0] = 10;
    }
    Mass(long x)
    {
        sizemass = x;
        p = new long double[x];
    }
    Mass(long x, long double znach)
    {
        sizemass = x;
        p = new long double[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            p[i] = znach;
        }
    }
    Mass(const Mass& object)
    {
        this->p = object.p;
        this->sizemass =  object.sizemass;
    }
    void out(void) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizemass; i++) {
            cout << p[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    Mass operator = (int znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Mass operator = (long double znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Mass operator += (int znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] + znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Mass operator += (long double znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] + znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Mass operator -= (int znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] - znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Mass operator -= (long double znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] - znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Mass operator *= (int znach) {
        for (int i = 0;i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] * znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Mass operator *= (long double znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] * znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Mass operator [] (int x) {
        return this->p[x];
    }
    friend Mass operator + (Mass& object1, int znach);
    friend Mass operator + (Mass& object1, long double znach);
    friend Mass operator - (Mass& object1, int znach);
    friend Mass operator - (Mass& object1, long double znach);
    friend Mass operator * (Mass& object1, int znach);
    friend Mass operator * (Mass& object1, long double znach);
};

Mass operator + (Mass& object1, int znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] + znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

Mass operator + (Mass& object1, long double znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] + znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

Mass operator - (Mass& object1, int znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] - znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

Mass operator - (Mass& object1, long double znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] - znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

Mass operator * (Mass& object1, int znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] * znach;
    }
    return temp;
}
Mass operator * (Mass& object1, long double znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] * znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    Mass v(8, 1);
    Mass m(6, 1);
    v += 4.1; // тут ошибка
    v.out();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `4.1` заменить на `4.1L` Вы сделали перегрузки для типов `int` и `long double`. Литерал `4.1` имеет тип `double`. Компилятор не может решить, какую перегрузку выбрать.

Comment: Как я понял, эту проблему можно решить с помощью шаблонных классов?

Comment: Можно и с помощью шаблонов.

Comment: Последний вопрос, почему мы добавляем L в конце? Понятно, что для того, чтобы дать компилятору знать, какой оператор мы хочем применить, но почему именно L?

Comment: Чтобы задать _тип_ литерала с плавающей точкой. Если суффикса нет, то литерал имеет тип `double`. Если есть суффикс `f` или `F`, то литерал имеет тип `float`. Если есть суффикс `l` или `L`, то литерал имеет тип `long double`. Так как есть перегруженный оператор, принимающий тип `long double`, то компилятор обнаруживает точное соответствие, и вызывает его. С другой стороны тип `double` может быть преобразован как в `int`, так и в `long double`. Ни один из этих двух типов в данном случае не имеет приоритета перед другим. Поэтому и проблемы с вызовом перегруженного оператора.